# Google Fonts provides different WOFF2 files between Chrome and Chromium

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, chromium

This can be reproduced with the following browsers:

Chrome: **Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

Chromium: **Version 62.0.3193.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)**

The font is retrieved with the following:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

In Chrome it returns:

```css
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

And in Chromium it returns:

```css
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), local('sans-serif'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), local('sans-serif'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), local('sans-serif'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), local('sans-serif'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), local('sans-serif'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), local('sans-serif'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), local('sans-serif'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Notice, the WOFF2 for Chrome is:

https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKOzY.woff2

Whereas the WOFF2 for Chromium is:

https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2

Aside from the filename difference, the chrome version is ~5kB larger, and the Chromium version renders the characters slightly smaller, causing inconsistent line breaks between browsers.

I haven't found an official explanation for this difference.  Is there a way to ensure a single version is retrieved, regardless of the requesting browser type?

Comment: This is no longer happening.  Anyone have any idea why this might have occurred?

Comment: I've asked sth similar, and there was one answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73238898/why-does-opera-display-googles-material-symbols-outlined-icon-font-incorrectl